# Receiving values from WCF Server

Tags: c#, wcf

I've setup a WCF Server and Client and all works nicely, i can call the method at the server and receive the object initialised from that call...great.

The problem i have is the Server receives some arguments when it's started, what i can't see is how i can obtain these values from the server as it appears i can't obtain a message or pre-initialised class from the server itself.

Is there a way to provide this information other than saving it to file when the server first receives it then reading that file from the server method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to have a singleton service object. This can be done by marking the service class with `ServiceBehavior` attribute and passing this object to `ServiceHost` constructor:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IExampleService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetInitValue();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ExampleService : IExampleService
{
    private readonly int initValue;

    public ExampleService(int initValue)
    {
        this.initValue = initValue;
    }

    public int GetInitValue() => initValue;
}

// ...

// public ServiceHost(object singletonInstance, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
var host = new ServiceHost(new ExampleService(someValue)));

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExampleService),
    new WSHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8080");
host.Open();
```

When singleton mode is not appropriate, one can use dependency injection, e.g. with Unity:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container
    .RegisterType<IExampleService, ExampleService>()
        // When service object is created, someValue is passed to it's constructor
        new InjectionConstructor(someValue));

var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ExampleService));

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExampleService),
    new WSHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8080")
    .EndpointBehaviors.Add(new UnityEndpointBehavior(container));

host.Open();

// ...

class UnityEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityEndpointBehavior(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider =
            new UnityInstanceProvider(container, endpoint.Contract.ContractType);
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}

class UnityInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;
    private readonly Type contractType;

    public UnityInstanceProvider(IUnityContainer container, Type contractType)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.contractType = contractType;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return GetInstance(instanceContext, null);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return container.Resolve(contractType);
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        container.Teardown(instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first option works perfectly, thanks :)